# Does return stop the rest of the script in php?

Tags: php

In php, is it safe to rely on `return` to stop the execution of the rest of the script? Or is there a better method than this?

**For Example:**

```
$x = 3;

if($x == 3){
    return false;
}

$a = 2;
$b = 2;

echo $a + $b;

echo 'You will never see me if x = 3';
```

Comment: Why the downvote with no explanation? Upvoting to make it even (and because as someone new to PHP I'm curious).

Comment: As you have it here, yes. If you use it within a function, no. Read the [PHP Reference](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.return.php)

Comment: @Obversity Downvoted because it's a really basic question more than adequately answered by the PHP reference manual. It has little or no value, and if the OP had bothered to do even the most basic research he wouldn't have needed to ask the question.

Comment: @Obversity, if you hover over the voting arrows, they describe the purpose of the voting.  And there is no requirement on SO for a voter to have to post a comment, although I do agree it is helpful.  That being said, I am guessing the high number of downvotes are because the poster has clearly shown no research effort, which is big on SO.  I searched google for ["does return stop the rest of the php script execution"](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.return.php) and the **first** result had the answer: [PHP return](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.return.php)

Comment: @MikeW: I believe you may be  incorrect regarding your answer about usage in functions. Please read the first sentence on the link you linked to regarding the `return` call within functions: "If called from within a function, the return statement immediately ends execution of the current function, and returns its argument as the value of the function call." However, you stated "If you use it within a function, no."

Comment: @SlyRaskal The questions asked were (a) whether it was safe, and (b) whether there was a better method to stop the script. 

This isn't simply "Does return stop a script". I agree that the OP probably could have found the answer via research though.

Comment: @Obversity, the answers to those questions can be inferred from understanding the answer to the question "Does return stop a script."  It's part of the research and critical thinking process regarding software development.  That's just the way I look at it, just my two cents.  Cheers.

Comment: @SlyRaskal Read my comments and the reference again. Called from within a function `return` stops the execution of the function. That is not the same as terminating the script. FWIW I think this dual usage is confusing and `return` should only be available within a function.

Comment: @MikeW, I think it is the wording that is confusing and it certainly got me after I reread it, thanks for the clarification. Cheers.

Comment: What if you find the PHP manual unclear and not that useful?  I came here from my search so I upvoted.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Lets say you have two files `a.php` and `b.php` on same folder

Code on `a.php`

```
$x = 3;

if($x == 3){
    return false;
}

$a = 2;
$b = 2;

echo $a + $b;

echo 'You will never see me if x = 3';
```

Code on `b.php`

```
include 'a.php';
echo 'i am still reachable';
```

If you run `a.php` you will see output `i am still reachable`. Because `return` take you back to the point from where the script was called.

If you used `exit()` instead of `return` you will not see that output. Because the script execution is ended immediately it sees `exit`.

Answer (score 0):

[`return`](http://www.php.net/return) won't necessarily stop the script. If that code is part of an [included](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.include.php) script a `return` will just end the inclusion.

> If called from the global scope, then execution of the current script file is ended. If the current script file was included or required, then control is passed back to the calling file. Furthermore, if the current script file was included, then the value given to return will be returned as the value of the include call. If return is called from within the main script file, then script execution ends.

Stop your script with [`exit()`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.exit.php).

Comment: In the example above, will it end the execution of the rest of the script? It does when I test it, but since I'm new to programming I maybe I'm doing something wrong.

Comment: I've put the word *necessarily* intentionally into my answer.

Answer (score 0):

Use `break();` or `exit();` both are working to stop the script